# Sequential count of values within factor level, ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, sequential

I have mark-recapture data in long form, and I want a column counting the number of times each individual has been seen at the time of each observation.

here is an example of the sort of data that I have:

```
dat<-tibble(ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),
           period=c("Aug.2012","Jun.2013","Aug.2013","Jun.2014","Aug.2014",
                    "Aug.2012","Jun.2013","Aug.2013","Jun.2014","Aug.2014"),
           length=c(12,NA,NA,15,19, NA,3,6,10,NA))
dat$sample.event<-rep(1:5,dim(dat)[1]/5)

# A tibble: 10 × 4
   ID    period   length sample.event
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>        <int>
 1 A     Aug.2012     12            1
 2 A     Jun.2013     NA            2
 3 A     Aug.2013     NA            3
 4 A     Jun.2014     15            4
 5 A     Aug.2014     19            5
 6 B     Aug.2012     NA            1
 7 B     Jun.2013      3            2
 8 B     Aug.2013      6            3
 9 B     Jun.2014     10            4
10 B     Aug.2014     NA            5
```

so I want a new column called `ind.obs` counting each time an individual has been seen, like this, but I want to keep the rows of the dataframe where the individual was *not* seen:

```
   ID   period length sample.event ind.obs
1   A Aug.2012     12            1       1
2   A Jun.2013     NA            2      NA
3   A Aug.2013     NA            3      NA
4   A Jun.2014     15            4       2
5   A Aug.2014     19            5       3
6   B Aug.2012     NA            1      NA
7   B Jun.2013      3            2       1
8   B Aug.2013      6            3       2
9   B Jun.2014     10            4       3
10  B Aug.2014     NA            5      NA
```

This seems like it should be possible using dplyr, but I can't figure it out.

I have tried:

```
dat%>%group_by(ID)%>%
  drop_na(length) %>%
  mutate(ind.obs=sequence(n()))

  ID    period   length sample.event ind.obs
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>        <int>   <int>
1 A     Aug.2012     12            1       1
2 A     Jun.2014     15            4       2
3 A     Aug.2014     19            5       3
4 B     Jun.2013      3            2       1
5 B     Aug.2013      6            3       2
6 B     Jun.2014     10            4       3
```

But as you can see, this completely removes the rows without observations.

I've also tried this, but get an error:

```
dat%>%group_by(ID) %>%mutate(ind.obs=sequence(n(na.rm=T)))

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `ind.obs = sequence(n(na.rm = T))`.
ℹ In group 1: `ID = "A"`.
Caused by error in `n()`:
! unused argument (na.rm = T)
```

Would appreciate any tips for resolving this, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet there's something sharper, but:

```
dat %>%   
  mutate(ind.obs = if_else(is.na(length), length, 
                           cumsum(!is.na(length))), .by=ID)
# Thanks @TarJae for the helpful improvement
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   ID    period   length sample.event ind.obs
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>        <int>   <dbl>
 1 A     Aug.2012     12            1       1
 2 A     Jun.2013     NA            2      NA
 3 A     Aug.2013     NA            3      NA
 4 A     Jun.2014     15            4       2
 5 A     Aug.2014     19            5       3
 6 B     Aug.2012     NA            1      NA
 7 B     Jun.2013      3            2       1
 8 B     Aug.2013      6            3       2
 9 B     Jun.2014     10            4       3
10 B     Aug.2014     NA            5      NA
```

Comment: That's good. By checking `is.na(length)` first we only need the `cumsum` in one term of the if_else. I'm gonna steal that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is great! 

Just for anyone else reading this, we might be using different versions of dplyr, because I didn't gt the "flag" column. Also `.by =` doesn't work for grouped dataframes, but `by =` works just fine.

Comment: Updated my answer, as the revision @TarJae suggested eliminated the step of the "flag" column. `.by` was introduced in dplyr 1.1.0

Comment: I'm running dplyr 1.1.2, and I get this with a grouped df (this isn't a problem with the answer at all, I didn't think to make my example grouped):
`Error in "mutate()":
! Can't supply ".by" when ".data" is a grouped data frame.
Run "rlang::last_trace()" to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: I guess there is an ambiguity between the received grouping and the newly specified grouping. Add `ungroup() %>% ` before the mutate step.

Answer (score 1):

We can try `cumsum` + `is.na` like below

```
> library(data.table)

> setDT(dat)[, ind.obs := NA^(is.na(length)) * cumsum(!is.na(length)), ID][]
    ID   period length sample.event ind.obs
 1:  A Aug.2012     12            1       1
 2:  A Jun.2013     NA            2      NA
 3:  A Aug.2013     NA            3      NA
 4:  A Jun.2014     15            4       2
 5:  A Aug.2014     19            5       3
 6:  B Aug.2012     NA            1      NA
 7:  B Jun.2013      3            2       1
 8:  B Aug.2013      6            3       2
 9:  B Jun.2014     10            4       3
10:  B Aug.2014     NA            5      NA
```

or similarily in `dplyr`

```
> dat %>%
+     mutate(ind.obs = NA^(is.na(length)) * cumsum(!is. .... [TRUNCATED]
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   ID    period   length sample.event ind.obs
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>        <int>   <dbl>
 1 A     Aug.2012     12            1       1
 2 A     Jun.2013     NA            2      NA
 3 A     Aug.2013     NA            3      NA
 4 A     Jun.2014     15            4       2
 5 A     Aug.2014     19            5       3
 6 B     Aug.2012     NA            1      NA
 7 B     Jun.2013      3            2       1
 8 B     Aug.2013      6            3       2
 9 B     Jun.2014     10            4       3
10 B     Aug.2014     NA            5      NA
```

Comment: So this dplyr solution works great `dat %>%  mutate(ind.obs = NA^(is.na(length)) * cumsum(!is.na(length)))`, but I don't really understand why. What is the carat doing in this context?

Comment: @ghaines `NA^(is.na(length))` works as a mask such that `NA` entries will yield `NA`s (similar to `ifelse` or `replace`)